# Python itertools' permutations() usage for several arrays

Tags: python

I'm constructing <strike>dictionaries</strike> lists in Python, with aim to iterate through each one individually and concatenate all different combinations. There are three different components to each "product" in a <strike>dictionary</strike> list:

1) a letter, e.g. `'A'` (first part of the product code, unique to each product entry). Let's say the range here is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

2) a letter and number, e.g. `'S2'` (2nd part, has several variations...might be `'D3'` or `'E5'` instead)

3) a period (`'.'`) and a letter, e.g. `'.X'` (3rd part, unique to each product entry). Let's say the range here is:

```
['.X', '.Y', '.Z']
```

Since the 2nd part listed above has the most variations, my starting assumption is to construct <strike>dicts</strike> lists with the 1st and 3rd parts together, in order to reduce the number of different lists<strike>dicts</strike>, since they are uniquely paired, e.g. '`A.Z'`...but, I would still need to split each entry then insert the 2nd part, between them, via some 'concatenate' command. So, question is: if I have another <strike>dict</strike> list with all variations of the 2nd part, what function(s) should I use to construct all variants of a product?

The total combination of examples:

```
ListOne = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ListTwo = ['D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5']
ListThr = ['.X', '.Y', '.Z']
```

I need to create new <strike>dicts</strike> lists as concatenations of all three <strike>dicts</strike> lists, e.g. `'AD3.X'`, but there are no variants for `ListOne` vs `ListThr`, it will always be `'A'` matched to `'.X'` or `'B'` and `'C'` matched to `'.Y'`...`ListTwo` products concatenated between `ListOne` and `ListThr` products will need to be iterated so all possible combinations are output as a new <strike>dict</strike> list e.g.

```
ListOneNew = ['AD3.X', 'AD4.X', AD5.X', 'AE3.X', 'AE4.X', 'AE5.X']
ListTwoNew = ['BD3.Y', 'BD4.Y', 'BD5.Y', <and so on...>]
```

For simplicity's sake, should the script have a merged version of `ListOne` and `ListThr` e.g.

```
List = ['A.X', 'B.X', 'C.Z']
```

and then split & concatenate with `ListTwo` products, or just have three `List`s and concatenate from there?

Comment: Those aren't dictionaries, those are *lists*...

Comment: All three? I thought that if both letters _and_ numbers are in a product name, it becomes a dictionary, whereas lists would be products made up only of letters.

Comment: No. Dictionaries and lists are completely different data structures.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

result = [a[0] + a[1] + a[2] for a in list(product(DictOne, DictTwo, DictThr))]
```

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension

```
final = sorted([a+b+c for c in DictThr for b in DictTwo for a in DictOne])
```